# Office 365 Javascript API tutorial implementation

Tags: javascript, excel, office365-apps

I want to implement an office 365 excel sheet with relevant toolbars inside my web based application - something like this (but also with the Excel Online toolbar above)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn848361.aspx

I am not sure how to go about it - is there a table and toolbar implementation in WinJS? Or is there an Office 365 widget that can be embedded?

Basically I want the look and feel of the Excel 365/Online implementation and don't want to implement the table in some other JS library

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes you can embed a  workbook as shown in the link above. From Excel Online, go to file > share > embed to get the embed code.